# "using System;" produces Compilation Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors

I haven't used .Net since 2005, so I copied the [ADO sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx#Y502) from Microsoft (which is shoddy at best), and got a Compilation Error at line 1:

> ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the
>   'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g.
>   Page or UserControl).

```
Line 1:  using System;
Line 2:  using System.Data;
Line 3:  using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

I put the sample code in a .aspx.cs file. Was I supposed to declare something before the `using …`?

Comment: The actual error would be useful.

Comment: @M.Babcock the `Line 1:` stuff is output from the compiler—of course I didn't put it in my code.

Comment: @Robinson I dunno why the error message didn't show up initially (I pasted it in when I posted the question).

Comment: @M.Babcock it's exactly like the example except I changed `Data Source=` to an IP address and `string queryString = "SELECT * from dbo.org_types;";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the MSDN code sample you're using wasn't prepared for use in a web page. Classes defined in a code behind should inherit from `Page` or `UserControl` and the Console application example from MSDN doesn't do either.

Perhaps one of the [ASP.NET tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/default.asp) would provide a better example.

Comment: Hm, okay. I had started out with the w3schools method, but it looked like it wasn't very safe (I'm used to PHP's PDO). Does .Net have something like that (I thought ADO was).

Comment: If you're just learning, I'd recommend something along the lines of ASP.NET MVC (good tutorials [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs)). If you can't do MVC then http://asp.net is a good resource.

Comment: Thanks! I only have to use .Net for one project and then I can go back to LAMP, so I'll probably stick with your MVC suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this issue is being caused by pasting the code sample over the page. The code samples provided are all for console applications. All you would be interested in is the code given in the Main() method. You would typically place that code in some event (page_load if you are just playing with it).

Comment: thanks! I don't remember what that means, but now I know what I'm looking for.